# how to load data into service on bootstrap in angular2 rc4

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrapping, angular2-services

Here is the scenario. I have two services injected. I want ensure that some data e.g. a base url is passed to the first service so that all following service have access to it.

Here's my root component

```
export class AppCmp {

  constructor (private httpService:HttpService, private SomeService:someService){}

}
```

here's the first service, lets assume it's a custom httpSerive

```
 @Injectable()
    export class HttpService{
      BASE_URL:string;
      constructor(private http:Http){
      }
      getAll(){ return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL) }
    }
```

here a second service, which will depend on the first one to perform a http.get request.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{
  constructor(private httpSerivce:HttpSerivce){
    this.httpService.getAll()...
  }
}
```

I DONT want to hard code the base url (or data) into the service and I don't want to involve localStorages, so I have two options: either in the main.ts (bootstrap file) or root component, assuming they are separated.

**The importance is that the data is available first thing and can be passed to or grabbed by the first injected service.**

Hope I could illustrate the topic and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide all kinds of value.

Register a provider using a string key (or an `OpaqueToken`)

```
{provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: someUrl}
```

and inject it like

```
constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseURL:string)
```

Answer (score 1):

for **RC4** do this in `main.ts`

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(HTTP_PROVIDERS);
let http = injector.get(Http);
let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage(),http);
authService.BASE_URL='you url goes here'


bootstrap(AppComponent, [ 
  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  [provide(AuthService, {useValue: authService})],
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

do this is `app.module.ts` but this code is for **RC5**

your service:

```
let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage(), http);
authService.BASE_URL='you url goes here'
```

and then add it into the providers array

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: AuthService, useValue: authService},
  ]
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed explanation, it actually solved another issue I have :)